# How to use Func<> in a List

Tags: c#

I have a program in which you can choose Yes or No in a menu-style option system. I would need it so the chosen option (Yes or No) returns a value to tell if the program continues or doesn't. I made it "work" by using "Action Selected" instead of the current "Func Selected" in the class but Action doesn't return a value, which I would need it to do.

```cs
List<Option> options;
bool cont;

do
{
    options = new List<Option>()
    {
        new Option("Yes", () => cont = true),
        new Option("No", () => cont = false)
    };

    int index = 0;
    Choices(options, options[index]);
    
    ConsoleKeyInfo keyinfo;
    
    do
    {
        keyinfo = Console.ReadKey();
    
        if (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow )
        {
            if (index + 1 < options.Count)
            {
                index++;
                Choices(options, options[index]);
            }
        }
    
        if (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
        {
            if (index - 1 >= 0)
            {
                index--;
                Choices(options, options[index]);
            }
        }
    
        if (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            options[index].Selected.Invoke();
            index = 0;
        }
    
    } while (keyinfo.Key != ConsoleKey.X);

} while (cont);

Console.WriteLine("Finished");

static void Choices(List<Option> options, Option selectedOption)
{
    Console.Clear();
    foreach (Option option in options)
    {
        if (option == selectedOption)
        {
            Console.Write("[ {0} ]", option.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("{0}", option.Name);
        }
    }
}

public class Option
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public Func Selected { get; set; }

    public Option(string name, Func selected)
    {
        Name = name;
        Selected = selected;
    }
}
```

I would only need that the chosen option returns the bool value to `cont`, and I'm not sure if `Func<>` is even the right way to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are asking - in your text, you say you are using `Action` instead of `Func`, but then your code does not include any mention of `Action`. And for what it's worth, lines like `new Option("Yes", cont = true)` don't look like your code would be compilable to start with.

Comment: `I'm not sure if Func<> is even the right way to do it` - it certainly doesn't seem that way from this code. `public bool Selected { get; set; }` would be fine.

Comment: Update: I see that uncompilable line has just been edited out - but the fact that it was there makes me assume this is a minimal sample that tries to reproduce the overall situation, not your actual code. (Which is a common dilemma when trying to keep questions clear and still not too long.) Thus, I am not sure in what aspects your full code might be different from this sample.

Comment: Replacing the Func<> with the bool like you suggested, the program now instantly shuts itself when I select "No", but it should only do it when "No" is selected and Enter is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Func<> to bool

```
public bool Selected { get; set; }
```

And setting "cont" value to the selected options bool value:

```
cont = options[index].Selected;
```

Seems to work (pretty much) in the way I wanted it to